# How change System Bar Progress Indicator Color in Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows Runtime, Universal)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

How change System Bar Progress Indicator Color in Windows Phone 8.1 (Windows Runtime, Univesal) like Facebook Beta App.

Image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/irLrJ.jpg

Obs.:

1 - The phone accent color it's not white (FGS)...
2 - The foreground color in system bar was already hooked to white...
3 - I already tried change the App.Resources like "PhoneAccentColor" and nothing...

Comment: According to this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/37ebb381-dd45-46f6-9f77-6439983670ca/override-color-of-statusbarprogressindicator?forum=wpdevelop, there's no way. You can, however, add your own progress bar on the top which would work the same way, only you can style it however you'd like.

Comment: Yes i know about it... I'm really curious about how Microsoft did that... I think the app have more system API access... I already test if that progress indicator it's an control progressbar and it's not...

Comment: Maybe some for inside #Microsoft can answer that because in the internet there is no how.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: Understood question incorrectly. Will get back when I find a solution.*

To achieve that you have to change the StatusBar ForegroundColor property. Since there is no way to change it through XAML, it has to be done through code behind like so:

```
StatusBar statusBar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
statusbar.ForegroundColor = Colors.Black;

///And then show or hide the Progressindicator like so
await statusBar.ProgressIndicator.ShowAsync();
await statusBar.ProgressIndicator.HideAsync();
```

I'm using this and it works perfectly.

For more info on the StatusBar (and it's baked in ProgressIndicator) check out these blog posts by Shawn Kendrot:

[Differences between the new StatusBar in Windows Phone XAML Apps and the SystemTray](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/07/Differences-between-the-new-StatusBar-in-Windows-Phone-XAML-Apps-and-the-SystemTray.aspx)

[Showing the system ProgressIndicator in a Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app](http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/06/Showing-the-system-ProgressIndicator-in-a-Windows-Phone-81-XAML-app.aspx)

Comment: "... 2 - The foreground color in system bar was already hooked to white... "

Comment: Can you show us an example of your code? Because it works for me. I've just changed the StatusBar ForegroundColor property to blue and it works perfectly. Here's a screenshot of the [StatusBar](http://imgur.com/hHjRm7I,B1ayFrf#0) and another of the [ProgressIndicator](http://imgur.com/hHjRm7I,B1ayFrf#1)

Comment: I created one static class to handle, but my code it's the same above...

In your screenshot the color of progress indicator is the **phone accent**, it's not the StatusBar Foreground...

Comment: Believe me, it is NOT the Phone Accent, the phone accent is overriden in my app and is set to MediumSeaGreen in my App.xaml as a resource. (<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneAccentBrush" Color="MediumSeaGreen"/>) I've only changed the second line of code in my example above into Colors.Blue. I can change it into any color and it works. Please supply us with some code you're using, so we might figure out where the problem is. I think you might have some code somewhere that's overriding this.

Comment: I already tried override PhoneAccentBrush but does not work... I did like you said, and nothing too...

My helper class: http://pastebin.com/evp4k07d

I'm using like this...

await Project.Helpers.StatusBarHelper.ShowLoading("teste");
await Task.Delay(3000);
Project.Helpers.StatusBarHelper.HideLoading();

Comment: You sure that your project is Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime (Not Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight)? 

My project is Universal...

Can you try with a new univesal project?

Comment: It's a WinPRT 8.1 project, not Silverlight, not Universal but Universal shouldnt matter. Either way, I apologize, I understood your question incorrectly, you meant the dots too and I thought just the text. I'll look further into it and I'll definitely get back to you.

Comment: Yes, the dots! :D

It's a limitation... see http://www.familie-smits.com/post/2014/06/21/theming-in-universal-apps.aspx 

But the Microsoft Facebook App team must have a solution, and i will look for it. ^^

Thank you!

Comment: I noticed. Might be indeed a special API call. No need to thank me haha. Thank me if I ever find the solution. ;P